# watir, get element by value

Tags: angularjs, watir, web-testing

using watir/cucumber/ruby for web page testing. Issue is that some fields cannot be located without javascript.

This is the part of the page I want to match:

```
<!-- ngIf: (!entry.valueIcon) --><div ng-if="(!entry.valueIcon)" class="ng-scope">
  <!-- valueAlt when value is not present or is on a separate object key such as valueFrom: { something: 'else' } -->
  <!-- ngIf: entry.valueAlt -->

  <!-- default value display -->
  <!-- ngIf: (!entry.valueAlt) --><input ng-if="(!entry.valueAlt)" type="text" class="form-control ng-valid ng-scope ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-minlength ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" ng-class="{ 'key-value-editor-set-focus-value-1006' : $last  }" id="key-value-editor-value-1006-0" name="key-value-editor-value-1006-0" ng-attr-placeholder="{{ (!isReadonlyAny) &amp;&amp; valuePlaceholder || ''}}" maxlength="" ng-model="entry.value" ng-readonly="isReadonlyAny || isReadonlySome(entry.name) || entry.isReadonly" placeholder=""><!-- end ngIf: (!entry.valueAlt) -->
</div><!-- end ngIf: (!entry.valueIcon) -->
```

In fact in web browser I have a value entered `XYZ`. But using `xpath` like `browser.element(xpath: %Q%*[@value="XYZ"]%)` doesn't find element. On the other hand, if I do `browser.element(id: "key-value-editor-value-1006-0").value` then the proper value of `XYZ` is returned.

Now you would ask why not select element by id. This is because this is a table of key/value pairs input fields. And I want to edit value by using the `key` value as a parameter. I don't want to keep separate code for each combination that happens to be needed.

Question is: is there any way to select the element only by providing the key value `XYZ` using watir selectors. i.e. what to put in place of `???` below?

`browser.element(???)`

Update: here is approach using javascript, but I am wondering if same thing can be done with plain watir selectors:

```
browser.browser.execute_script(%Q%var p = new RegExp("^BARBATRON$"); var el = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); for (var i=0; i<el.length; i++) { if (p.test(el[i].value)) return el[i]; }%).click
```

Comment: I do not believe the XPath `%Q%*[@value="XYZ"]%` is correct. I believe it should be `%Q%//*[@value="XYZ"]%`. Though I do not believe that is the root of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a limitation (or bug?) in Selenium-Webdriver. It looks like you can only locate the element based on the value when the page loads. You cannot locate the element using the changed value.

```
# Element can be located using its original value
browser.text_field(value: 'initial value').exists?
#=> true
browser.text_field(xpath: '//*[@value="initial value"]').exists?
#=> true

# The value is changed
browser.text_field.set('new value')

# Element cannot be found using the new value
browser.text_field(value: 'new value').exists?
#=> false
browser.text_field(xpath: '//*[@value="new value"]').exists?
#=> false

# Element can still be found using the original value
browser.text_field(value: 'initial value').exists?
#=> true
browser.text_field(xpath: '//*[@value="initial value"]').exists?
#=> true
```

The only solution appears to be iterating through the elements as you have done. Though I personally would prefer to do it in Ruby:

```
field = browser.text_fields.find { |t| t.value == 'XYZ' }
```

Comment: Awesome, do you know if there is an existing bug filed for that? Your examples don't show it very critical, but angular web app seems to be generating this table on the fly, hence all values seem to be like changed values. Thus watir can't locate based on them regardless if user changed them or not.

Comment: There definitely is no bug logged for Watir as the problem can be reproduced with Selenium-WebDriver. I could not find a Selenium bug.

Comment: This isn't a bug per se.  It's the difference between the value attribute and the value property.  XPath can only query against the attribute values, and when the value of a field is updated it is the property that gets updated, not the attribute

Comment: That is unfortunate. Thanks for the clarification @TomWalpole.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I understand, I don't see a value attribute in your html.
Perhaps something like this:

```
browser.element(id: /key-value-editor-value-\d{4}-0/).value
```

or this:

```
key = "1006"
browser.element(id: "key-value-editor-value-#{key}-0").value
```

Comment: This table is dynamically generated by angularjs. I don't know key numbers in advance to use them for selection. I just want to select the input field that has value "something". I know HTML doesn't contain the value. See question. `element.value` does return the value properly. But I can't figure out a selector that would select the element based on that value.